# Why can't I use a typedef from a header file which is included in a precompiled header in VC++?

Tags: c, visual-c++, header-files

So I'm trying to learn some C since I might need it for next semester of college, and I have a little problem in Visual C++ with precompiled headers:

I do something like this in **header1.h:**

```
typedef struct {
    int example;
} randstruct;
```

Then I do this in **header2.h:**

```
#include "header1.h"
```

Then I do this in **main.c:**

```
#include "header2.h"

int main()
{
    randstruct *s;
}
```

Where **header2.h** is the precompiled header. Doing this results in the program not recognizing the struct and giving me errors, claiming that randstruct and s are undeclared identifiers. Doing this outside of the precompiled header (simply in another header) does seem to work, and doing this with function prototypes rather than typedef seems to work as well. What's going on? Is this a VC++ issue or am I misinterpreting something?

PS: I assume someone's going to tell me that this is bad practice or something, and that might be, but that still leaves my curiosity. Also, the standard generated precompiled header in VC++ contains a **#include**  and for some reason I can use typedefs like **FILE** normally, despite it being defined in a header file included in the precompiled header which in turn is included in my main c file.

Comment: Are you sure that the PCH file was recreated after `randstruct` typedef was added to `heeader1.h`?  Try deleting the PCH file and rebuilding.

Comment: @MichaelBurr not entirely sure what you're talking about. I think that's not the issue since it seems that it works normally with other header files, but not the precompiled header. Regardless, I did delete the file and rebuild, but it's giving the exact same errors.

Comment: @MichaelBurr oh! I get it now. Wow, I feel like an idiot. The concept of precompiled headers just now came to me. The header is actually literally compiled only once when it's created, and whenever I want to add something new to it, I have to let it recompile the precompiled header file specifically. I had to use the VC++ Create command to let it recreate the file for me AFTER the definition was added. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I didn't understand the concept of precompiled headers properly. Basically, a precompiled header is compiled only once. Not once for each build, but literally just once whenever it's created (I guess mostly on project creation). This is because header compilation/preprocessing can take really long for big projects, and if you have a big header file which barely ever changes, it's best to use it as a precompiled header.

If you alter the precompiled header source file and want the changes to take effect, you have to recompile it, otherwise the old version of the header file will remain in use by the application rather than the updated version.

Simply go to
**Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Precompiled Headers**.

1. If you want to recreate the precompiled header on build every time (not recommended, especially for large projects, but may be useful for small test projects), choose **Create (/Yc)**.
2. Otherwise you can recreate it once by choosing **Create (/Yc)**, building
   it once, and then resetting the precompiled header setting to **Use (/Yu)**. There should be other ways, but this is the only way I know.

The reason my **typedef** wasn't recognized by the compiler was because I didn't recreate the precompiled header file after defining the struct and including the header file in the source of the precompiled header, so the compiler kept using the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Before the compiler compiles your code it's start by checking it. And the checking process is based on the text code. When you compile the header file (`header2.h`) it gives a binary file and the compiler couldn't know if the header containing the type `randstruct` (`header1.h`) is included in that binary file (precompiled `header2.h`). You can only use precompiled functions and include headers containing prototypes of these precompiled functions so that your compiler could know about these functions. And that's why library files always comes with header files.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Why then are variable definitions not found, while prototype function declarations are? Also, take stdio.h for example. VC++ automatically includes this in the precompiled header, and I can use any typedef declared in it normally when including it in my main program, like the FILE variable. Why is this then?

Comment: Ah, never mind. I got the problem. I'm not sure if it's what you meant to say, but I'll post my solution right now. Your answer helped me with my suspicions, and Michael Burr's comment on my question was basically spot on.